# Probability of absorption and emission of photons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, atomic-physics

Suppose you have a single electron in a box, and you shoot a single photon at it.

How does one calculate the probability that the photon will be absorbed and the particle excited? Or that the photon will stimulate emission?

Comment: have a look at this and links therein http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod5.html

Comment: Have a look at this too http://nicadd.niu.edu/~piot/phys_630/Lesson17.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the links. However, neither quite answer the question I'm trying to ask. The first doesn't talk about probabilities at all. The second talks about probabilities in the case of an atom in an optical cavity.

Comment: I thought that the second one would illustrate the necessity of solving for specific boundary conditions to get at probabilities. For example in Merzbacher's quantum mechanics second edition , chapter 6 there is a solution for a potential well problem fig 6.11 where the transmision  coefficient, which is related to probabilities, is computed for a square well potential and a particle scattering either below the potential level or above, for an electron scattering by the potential well.

Comment: For the three body problem, nucleus electron and incoming photon the problem is treated with quantum field theory graphs and not by solving an approximate potential problem in the Schrodinger  equation, specific problems and boundary conditions.

Comment: See this http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node469.html ( amplitude square is probability). So it is not a simple question to answer here.